# How do I link the Ubuntu One logo from my blog?

Tags: blog

Is there any code to link the Ubuntu One logo from my blog so that I can access it from there whenever I want and also to promote Ubuntu One?

Comment: Love the idea by the way :) Posted an answer, please check about any copyright issues before using the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The image on the bottom-right of the [UbuntuOne](https://one.ubuntu.com/) site can maybe serve you as a logo. And putting that in-between link tags making the logo point to [UbuntuOne](https://one.ubuntu.com/) can maybe serve your purpose. That way, if you are logged into UbuntuOne, your dashboard will directly open up giving access to your files. If not, then, will take you to the [UbuntuOne](https://one.ubuntu.com/) homepage

Something like this:

```
<a href="http://one.ubuntu.com/"><img src="https://media.one.ubuntu.com/media/4622/img/com/u1-small.png" /></a>
```

Not sure if it's a copyright violation of some sort, so please do confirm that there is no violation of any sort before you put this into action. This answer is just to prove you can do it.